# String manipulations to separate values

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I have a string of the format `MASTER CARD 01/01/2012`, I need to grab the date part separately.

Sometimes it could be `VISA 01/01/2012`, I have tried splitting by the space but got stuck when there are two spaces like in the case of `MASTER CARD 01/01/2012`.

Any help would be much appreciated;

```
string date = e.Brick.Text;
string[] dates = date.Split(' ');
```

Comment: How do you get stuck when there are two spaces? You do get the date in the last element of `dates`, right?

Comment: Sorry Mt Lister newbie here and learning.. appreciate your patience

Comment: Hey, you don't have to apologise for being a newbie. We're all newbies in some field or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way your strings look, you will get the date in your last element in array.

```
//dates[dates.Length-1] should have date

    string date = "MASTER CARD 01/01/2012";
    string[] dates = date.Split(' ');
    Console.WriteLine(dates[dates.Length - 1]);
```

A proper solution should be to check each item against DateTime, something on the following line

```
DateTime tempDs = new DateTime();
            foreach (string str in dates)
            {

                if (DateTime.TryParse(str, out tempDs))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Found Date");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all the dates for the various cards have similar formatting, Regular Expressions could be a viable alternative.

`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
Match mDate = Regex.Match(e.Brick.Text, @"\b(?<date>(?:\d{1,2}[\\/-]){2}\d{4})\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);
if (mDate.Success)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Date: {0}", mDate.Groups["date"].Value));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your code.

If the date is always at the end of the string you can do something like

```
year = dates[dates.Length-1]
```

And so on for month and day

Answer (score 0):

Split by spaces and use the [DateTime.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1.aspx) method to parse the dates.  The method should fail for VISA, MASTER, and CARD; but it will succeed for the date parts of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative:

```
string date = e.Brick.Text.Substring(e.Brick.Text.LastIndexOf(' ')+1);
```

Comment: Notice with this approach you don't need to split or have an auxiliary array at all.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
public string ExtractDateTimeString(string s){

    return s.Split(' ').Where(x => 
            {
                DateTime o;
                return DateTime.TryParse(x, out o);
            }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or another way:

```
        string text = "MASTER CARD 4.5.2012";
        string[] split = text.Split(' ');

        string mc = "";
        string date = ""; //when you get this value, you can easily convert to date if you need it

        foreach (string str in split)
        {
            if (char.IsNumber(str[0]))
            {
                date = str;
                mc = mc.Remove(mc.Length - 1, 1);
            }
            else
                mc += str + " ";
        }
```